# How to run Meta-analysis when data are given in OR and CI

Tags: stata, meta-analysis, biostatistics

I am currently working on my Master's Thesis (meta-analysis) and I have identified some articles with only OR given, so I have calculated the OR and CI for all of the articles to ensure they're in a consistent format.

Unfortunately, I am a bit stuck now as I have no clue how to go about using the appropriate commands to run the meta-analysis as examples in manuals are only given in 2 x 2 tables.

Comment: You may want to rephrase this in a software-neutral way. Questions about how to use Stata are off topic here.

Comment: Oh my apology. I just so happen to see other threads discussing Stata specifically: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157876/user-weight-specification-in-meta-analysis-using-stata?rq=1 

Wasn't aware this is off-topic

Answer (score 2):

As far as the statistical part of your question is concerned you need to convert the OR and the limits of the CI to the log scale. Then calculate the standard error of the log(OR) from the log(CI limits). You then have what you need for your Stata command. I do not use Stata myself but perhaps the key phrase you need to search for is inverse variance weighted.